# HTML image src case sensitivity

Tags: html, case-sensitive

I have image folder names in caps. But the `src` is in lowercase, so this is not loading images.

I can't make all the image folders lowercase, so I want to change my code to take a case insensitive path.

I have a link like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
  <img id="productMainImage" src="images/Tulips.jpg" alt="image" escapeXml="false" class="product_main_image"/>
</a>
```

I want to make the image src as case insensitive; meaning I want my 
code to work even if `src ="IMAGES/Tulips.jpg"`.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: There is no way to do this in HTML.

Answer (score 6):

Either you can use JS to do this using `toLowerCase()`, or you need to rename them by yourself.

Also, it depends on the server, and HTML has *nothing to do with this*, UNIX Servers are *case sensitive*, whereas Microsoft servers are *case insensitive*.

Also if you are using any server side language, like PHP, you can use `strtolower()` as well which would be even better, as client can have JavaScript turned off in which, your page will fail to render images.

Comment: Actually only the interpretion of node names in filesystems is case insensitive on MS-Windows systems. Some other things _are_ case sensitive. MS-Windows is not exactly consequent in this. It is a hack.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use .htaccess and RewriteRule to change the path on request.
Something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^IMAGES/(.*)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ images/$1.$2
```

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what OS your web server is running - for example OSX is not case sensitive on the file system but Linux is.

You could create a regex to rewrite the request - apache offers mod_rewrite - but I find it best to create a convention and stick to it - I assume things will be case sensitive so that if I port the site I do not have any issues.